# What is the difference between NestedScrollingChild, NestedScrollingChild2 and NestedScrollingChild3 in Android?

Tags: android, difference

What is the difference between:

1. NestedScrollingChild:
   https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/NestedScrollingChild
2. NestedScrollingChild2:
   https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/NestedScrollingChild2
3. NestedScrollingChild3:
   https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/NestedScrollingChild3

any performance improvements or what?

Answer (score 1):

These are just interfaces, so performance would depend on the implementations. The reason there are probably 3 different versions is to introduce newer APIs without affecting existing components that already conform to one of the earlier `NestedScrollingChild` interfaces.